# Hint: Hint: Hint: Hint: Hint:

Tags: riddle, word

At 23 I am cold. But at 8 all I did was

Hint:

> 

Hint:

> 

Hint:

> 

Hint:

> 

Hint:

> 

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think the answer is

> inter

At 23 I am cold

> **W** is the 23rd letter of the alphabet and prepending **W** to *inter* gives *Winter*

But at 8 all I did was...

> **H** is the 8th letter of the alphabet and prepending **H** to *inter* gives *Hinter* - which is someone prone to giving hints.